# how to deploy/Copy only _PublishedWebsites in dropfolder in tfs?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Can anyone please help me how to deploy only _PublishedWebsites in dropfolder in build server,as i have the solution in which it has web application and class-libraries referenced to it, In the Build server when i check the drop folder it contains the repetitive assemblies as shown below.

- _PublishedWebsite
- ClassLib1.dll
- ClassLib2.dll
- website.dll

I dont want to have this assemblies(classlib1.dll,classlib2.dll and  website.dll) to be created again in the dropfolder as these are already present in the _publishedWebSite/website/bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out this by editing the xaml as posted by me in the below link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/1c6af252-d714-4daf-837d-9e1a4fca794c